# The difference between viewport and responsive web

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I want to know what's the difference between `<meta name='viewport'>` and Responsive web design using CSS Media Screen?

Because these two things seem alike in functionality.

With or without `<meta name='viewport'>`, just by setting Media Screen I still can set different layouts for different screen sizes and the layouts automatically detect the screen sizes then set the matching layouts

Comment: The viewport meta tag tells browsers how to render a page properly—especially useful on smaller screens like those on mobile phones and tablets. You can set initial scale to which the content will be rendered at, you can disable/enable zooming, you can set the initial width and height of the viewport separately. All these factors help designers to dictate a specific layout for mobile devices.

Comment: Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/), [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972) and [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport).

Answer (score 0):

**Viewport** meta tag almost uses some other options like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, , maximum-scale=1">
```

Through these options you can define some behaviors for your responsive website. Using `<meta name='viewport'>` without its options does not have any special affect on your website, although it can still be responsive.

You can check this page to get more information:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="viewport">` tells browsers with small screens how they should map the CSS pixels onto real pixels. Essentially it is there to say "We've bothered to care about phone sized screens, don't zoom out" to the browser.

It is a prerequisite for (sanely) implementing responsive web design, not an alternative approach to it.